# Insertion condition if the stack is not empty in python

Tags: python, algorithm, stack, queue

I have a problem implementing the following requirement for a stack queue implementation job:

***After each worker receives their first box, they can only receive n other boxes if the box at the top of their pile is greater than or equal to the weight of the box to be received***

I was able to implement it, however, it is not properly completed because it only works with a certain part of the tests

```py
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.boxes_stack = Stack()

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.insert(0, item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def front(self):
        return self.items[-1]

    def rear(self):
        return self.items[0]


class Stack:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = []
        self.sum_weights = 0

    def isEmpty(self):
        return self.items == []

    def push(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)
        if type(item) is not list:
            self.sum_weights += item

    def pop(self):
        return self.items.pop()

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[len(self.items) - 1]

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def top(self):
        return self.items[-1]


quantity_loaders_boxes = int(input())
box_weights = input().split(' ')
row_boxes = Queue()
loaders_queue = Queue()
remaining_boxes = Queue()
stack_boxes_sorting = Stack()
for i in box_weights:
    row_boxes.enqueue(int(i))

print(f'Load List: {row_boxes.items}')
print(f'Reverse Load List: {row_boxes.items[::-1]}')
print(f'Start of The Queue: {row_boxes.front()}')
print(f'End of The Line: {row_boxes.rear()}')

for i in range(0, quantity_loaders_boxes):
    loader_i = Queue()
    loaders_queue.enqueue(loader_i)

for j in row_boxes.items:
    for i in loaders_queue.items:
        if i.boxes_stack.isEmpty():
            if not row_boxes.isEmpty():
                i.boxes_stack.push(row_boxes.dequeue())
        else:
            if not row_boxes.isEmpty():
                if i.boxes_stack.top() >= row_boxes.front():
                    i.boxes_stack.push(row_boxes.dequeue())

for counter, i in enumerate(loaders_queue.items):
    print(f'{counter + 1}º changer => {i.boxes_stack.items} | Sum of Weights => {i.boxes_stack.sum_weights}')
    stack_boxes_sorting.push(i.boxes_stack.items)

print(f'Stack of Sorted Boxes: {sorted(stack_boxes_sorting.items, reverse=True)}')
print('Orderly stack of boxes: ', end='')
print(*sorted(stack_boxes_sorting.items, reverse=True))

print(f'Load List After Removals: {row_boxes.items}')
print(f'Reverse Load List After Removals: {row_boxes.items[::-1]}')
```

From this input:

```
3
4 4 1 3 5 2 6 7 8 9
```

I expected to receive the following output:

```
Load List: [9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4]
Reverse Load List: [4, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1º changer => [4, 3, 2]
2º changer => [4]
3º changer => [1]
Load List After Removals: [9, 8, 7, 6, 5]
Reverse Load List After Removals: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

But I received the following output:

```
Load List: [9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 5, 3, 1, 4, 4]
Reverse Load List: [4, 4, 1, 3, 5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1º changer => [4, 3] | Sum of Weights => 7
2º changer => [4] | Sum of Weights => 4
3º changer => [1] | Sum of Weights => 1
Load List After Removals: [9, 8, 7, 6, 2, 5]
Reverse Load List After Removals: [5, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: if i understand your question right, the condition would be as follows: in your push method you just call the peek method to get the upmost element and check its weight attribute. if it is higher than the weight of the actual element, then put the element on top otherwise throw an exception/error.

Comment: More or less. And now that you spoke, I thought of a possible way that would be to implement a method to take the first element of the stack without removing it and comparing it with the element to be received from the list

Comment: @user3192295 , explaining better how this requirement works, it would work as follows: As soon as the first boxes were added to the charger's batteries, the charger would only receive another box in its stack if the weight of the box at the top of its stack is greater than or equal to the weight of the next box out of the box row.